# How to conditionally exit in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have few steps in my script. I am testing it for 1000 users.

```
1. Validate username
2. Validate Password
3. User Info
4. Settings
5. Payments
20. Logout
etc...
```

I would get a token on password call, if call is success and then I would extract token run all the steps..

But If this is failed, then I don't want run all the step on the thread because it will definitely fail. It should go to step 1 again rather than running all the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider put your steps until token created inside [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)

> The While Controller runs its children until the condition is "false".

As a controller `Condition` field you can check last sampler failed (assert that token is extracted)

```
${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
```

And it will loop until token retrieve and continue flow

Comment: The same thread will continuously run till token comes, or this will be a new thread?

Comment: We have to wait SLA 15 sec. but this will take until token gets generated. Is there any other way to quit that thread and start new thread?

Comment: @ChanGan You can quit using Test Action, but I don't think inside test start a new thread is good practice in JMeter

Comment: Test Action does not have any condition. Can we stop current thread and not execute the remaining and will start new thread from step1 By using Start Next Thread loop?